# How to concatenate the result of two functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

The first two functions produce numbers, and the third should join them, but I'm unsure as to why `joinNums()` doesn't work.

```
// random number between specified params
function randInteger() {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 10;
  const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  console.log(randomInteger);
}

function randDecimal() {
  let decimal = 100;
  let integral = 100;
  const randomDecimal =
    Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (integral * decimal - 1 * decimal) + 1 * decimal
    ) /
    (1 * decimal);
  console.log(randomDecimal);
}

function joinNums() {
  let randomDecimal;
  let randomInteger;
  randInteger();
  randDecimal();
  console.log("" + randomDecimal + randomInteger);
}
```

Comment: I've also tried ```console.log(`${randomDecimal}${randomInteger}`)```

Comment: `return randomnInteger` at the end of function 1 and `return randomDecimal` from function 2. Also you need to remove `let randomDecimal` and `let randomInteger;` and instead do `function joinNums() { console.log("" + randomDecimal() + randomInteger()); }`

Comment: @ksingh your functions should return the result. Then you take an output and do whatever you need to do with it

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: either return and assign or declare `randomDecimal` and `randomDecimal` as global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're not assigning the function results to the variables.
2. Your functions should `return` the result, not `console.log` it.
3. You need to call `joinNums()` (you don't seem to be).

So (see `***`):

```js
// random number between specified params
function randInteger() {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 10;
  const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return randomInteger; // ***
}

function randDecimal() {
  let decimal = 100;
  let integral = 100;
  const randomDecimal =
    Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (integral * decimal - 1 * decimal) + 1 * decimal
    ) /
    (1 * decimal);
  return randomDecimal; // ***
}

function joinNums() {
  let randomDecimal = randDecimal();  // ***
  let randomInteger = randInteger();  // ***
  console.log(`${randomDecimal}${randomInteger}`);
}

joinNums();  // ***
```

Or of course, you can just call them directly rather than writing to variables first:

```
function joinNums() {
  console.log(`${randDecimal()}${randInteger()}`); // ***
}
```

```js
// random number between specified params
function randInteger() {
  let min = 1;
  let max = 10;
  const randomInteger = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  return randomInteger; // ***
}

function randDecimal() {
  let decimal = 100;
  let integral = 100;
  const randomDecimal =
    Math.floor(
      Math.random() * (integral * decimal - 1 * decimal) + 1 * decimal
    ) /
    (1 * decimal);
  return randomDecimal; // ***
}

function joinNums() {
  console.log(`${randDecimal()}${randInteger()}`);
}

joinNums();  // ***
```